# Disable options already selected in another multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen this working with a single select box, but couldn't manage to do it with multiple select boxes.

Let's say i have two multiple selects:

```
<select class='test' multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select class='test' multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I manage to lock the option audi if selected in any of the select boxes?

I was trying using:

```
    $(document).on('change', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.test').find('option').prop('disabled', false);
         $('.test').each(function() {
         $('.test').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
         });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please explain the problem a little bit more? I've inserted your code into a jsFiddle and it appears to be locking the selected option on the non-selected list (to my understanding these are the expected results). https://jsfiddle.net/6p7pshLp/

Comment: add a fiddle or snippet. how the document is being changed?

Comment: @Hodrobond That`s it.. If you select more than one option, it locks only the first one selected..

Comment: @dante When I click an element on the left list, it becomes greyed out on the right side (and vice versa). If I switch the element I clicked, the previously disabled element becomes clickable again and the new element's counterpart becomes disabled. Please check my fiddle from the previous comment =)

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I understand now. You'd like to have the ability to select multiple items from each list? I'll fiddle with it shortly.

Comment: @Hodrobond Yes, but if you press control and select more than one item on one of the selects, it disables only the first one on the other list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the value and pass it to the other option. Like this:

```
 $('.test').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).children(':selected').val();
    $('.test').val(selected);
 });
```

http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/KrZRXj

- EDIT -
  i changed it to accept an array of values

  ```
  $('.test').on('change', function() {
      var selected = $(this).val();
      $('.test').val(selected);
  });
  ```
- EDIT -
  I recommend to use checkboxs than multiple select. Is more user friendly, intuitive and easier to select/disable the different options. (see the codepen)

  ```
  // 2 arguments: the first group of cars and the other group of cars
  function selectCar(carInputs, otherCarInputs) {
    carInputs.each(function(){
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        //  it is checked
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log('checked: '+ value );

          //filter otherCarsInputs and disable the one that the user selected.
          otherCarInputs.filter(function(){
              if(this.value === value) {
                  return true;
              } 
          }).prop('disabled', 'disabled');

      } else {
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log('unchecked: '+ value );

          //do the inverse. is the user uncheck the input, enable it on the other team
          otherCarInputs.filter(function(){
              if ($(this).is(':disabled') && this.value == value) {
                  return true;
              }
          }).prop('disabled', '');
      }
    });
  }

  //on each input, calls the function with the right parameters (group car)
  $('input').on('change', function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('car1') ) {
          selectCar($('.car1'), $('.car2'));
     } else {
          selectCar($('.car2'), $('.car1'));
     }
  });
  ```

Comment: Okay, check it again, now should work. To select multiple value you need to press ctrl key. (cmd for mac)

Comment: Actually, there`s something that shouldn`t happen. If I select an option on a list, I shouldn`t be able to unclick it on the other list..

Comment: One question. When i change the second list, the first list should update its values?

Comment: If I select Volvo on the first list, it disables it on the second list, if I go back to list 1 and uncheck volvo, it enables it back on the second list.. and that can happens on the other way around as well.. And I shouldn`t be able to uncheck it on the second list if I selected it on the first one..

Comment: I got lost. You start with all unchecked. If I check Volvo on listA, it happens nothing on listB. if i check volvo on listB, uncheck it on listA, is that right?

Comment: No.. starts all unchecked, if i check volvo on listA, disables it on listB, but I can't uncheck it on listB.. and that can happens checking Audi on listB, it disables on listA but I can't uncheck it on listB.. is that clear?

Comment: i couldnt figure out a way that handles both lists. What do you intend to do with this? Where isn't a easier way to accomplish it? It seems very entropic to understand, maybe it is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Sandrita its a list of players, and if they are selected on team A, they shouldn't be selected on team B.. and also if I select the player on team A, I shouldn`t be able to unselect it on team B..

Comment: why don't you use checkbox inputs? it is a lot easier to target the values.

Comment: Because, it`s a lots of players. It won't look nice i think.

Comment: you can stylish each input to look like a select box you know... today i'm tired. but tomorrow morning i can try it. if you still want it to :)

Comment: That's cool.. if u have an easier way.. I would appreciate. Obrigado

Comment: okay, check it again. now if you select one checkbox, it disables the other team. not i just need to do the opposite (check it again when available). tomorrow i'll do it.

Comment: hey! i figured out a way!  let me know if is what you wanted!

Comment: Sandrina, yes.. that should do.. but have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/4ep92810/124/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it other way

```
$('.test option').click(function(){
  var op = $(this).attr('value');
  // commented out for multiple select ability
  //$('.test option').attr('disabled', null);
  $('.test option[value='+op+']').not(':selected').attr('disabled', $(this).filter(':selected').length > 0 ? true : null);
});
```

Comment: Right, but now if I select more than one value, it only disables one of them.

Comment: Hmm strange. It should be triggered by every click on any option... Give me a minute, I'm writing from mob. phone, no execution env. under hands

Comment: I have modified answer again. But no clue why disabled one only... Every click should be proceeded, one click - one +/- disabled option.

Comment: Look, http://jsfiddle.net/4ep92810/120/ cant get it working.. althought I tried without selectpicker and it worked.

Comment: Oh... You didn't say (and no corresponding tags with question) that you use bootstrap. This absolutely change the matter! Look at html layout with bootstrap and w/o.

Comment: I see.. but is it too different to that?

Comment: This is a very big difference! Bootstrap replaces all `option` elements with `a` that in turn contains span and more elements inside. So our (who answered) approaches are ruined about bootstrap hidden work. You can look at html layout when bootstrap works, you'll likely not recognize your source html

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be shorter and more straightforward using jQuery:

```
$('#select-element-id option').on('click', function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```